# Time Frequency Signal Analysis in Mathematica (MMA)

Tags: time-frequency

I want to know " Whether there is any Tool Box in Mathematica (MMA) for the Time-Frequency (TF) Signal Analysis".

I am well-versed in MMA Programming, so want to do TF Signal Analysis in MMA. I think if there is toolbox of TF Analysis, then it will be of very much great help in long programming.

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: See [my question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5977/time-frequency-analysis-beyond-wavelets) in mathematica.SX.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an older version of *Mathematica* (pre v.8) and are interested in wavelets - yes, you need an add-on to perform wavelet analysis. More about it [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4639/). If you are using v.8 or above then everything wavelet-related is built-in. If you are interested in Fourier analysis - it is built in (since v.1). To showcase the capabilities of the time-frequency analysis functionality:

Suppose we have the signal $2 \exp \left(-\frac{t^2}{10}\right) \cos (5 t)$
[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can visualise its Gabor transform

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Wigner transform (notice the artifacts)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the (somewhat) corrected Gabor-Wigner transform

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A second test signal

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and its spectrogram calculated using partitions of length 256, offset 1 and BlackmanHarrisWindow

[image: Mathematica graphics]

its periodogram (with the same options as above)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we move onto wavelets
Scalogram after a continuous wavelet transform with a Morlet wavelet

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the respective scalogram after performing a discrete wavelet transform

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just because I find it pretty - a scalogram of a simulated noise in 3D

[image: Noise]

Comment: It's a pitty that you did not share the code...

Comment: @anderstood I will dig through my VC and search for those specific samples ^^